# Try catch code block not executing in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a try-catch sentence in a multiplayer project for checking the connection status (via UDP) in Unity. It receives a callback from server in the try codeblock, and the catch codeblock is for getting the exception in case the connection is interrupted suddenly. My problem is that the catch block doesn't execute the code I use for informing the user that the connection has been lost with the server. It only seems to execute code relative to the exception (like Debug.Error(e)).

```
//Callback from server connection
        private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult _result) {
            try {
                //Ends connection
                socket.EndConnect(_result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
               //These three lines are the problem. They won't execute
                UIManager.instance.logPanel.enabled = true;
                UIManager.instance.logPanel.text = "Servidor no disponible";
                UIManager.instance.HideUsernameSelection();
            }

            //If theres no connection to the server the function returns
            if (!socket.Connected) 
            {
                return;
            }

            //Reference to data stream
            stream = socket.GetStream();

            //Packet for data received from server
            receivedData = new Packet();

            //Read
            stream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveCallback, null);
        }
```

Is there anyway to force the catch block to execute the code inside it?

Comment: socket.EndConnect seems to be ending a connection (as per comments in code and MS docs). I don't see any connect method in the try, so why do you expect to catch the error?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt copied the whole function. I just updated it. What i want is to execute the functions from UIManager if the callback from connecting to server is negative, so i can show the reconnection UI and the server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the issue is that this call comes in **async** so on a different Thread/Task.

Most of Unity API can only be used on the Unity main thread. (Only exception are basically all pure mathematical structs that do not directly influence or rely on the scene.)

Most of the time this is solved via a so called "Main Thread Dispatcher". It looks somewhat like e.g.

```
public class MainThreadDispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Singleton Pattern
    private static MainThreadDispatcher _instance;

    public static MainThreadDispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance) return _instance;

            _instance = FindObjectOfType<MainThreadDispatcher>();
            
            if(_instance) return _instance;

            _instance = new GameObject(nameof (MainThreadDispatcher)).AddComponent<MainThreadDispatcher>();
        }  
    }

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            return;
        }

        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Dispatcher
    private readonly Queue<Action> _actions = new Queue<Action>();

    private void LateUpdate ()
    {
        lock (_actions)
        {
            while(_actions.Count > 0)
            {
                var action = _actions.Dequeue();

                action?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    public void DoInMainThread(Action action)
    {
        lock(_actions)
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(action);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And then you would rather dispatch anything that is Unity API related like e.g.

```
try
{
    //Ends connection
    socket.EndConnect(_result);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    MainThreadDispatcher.Instance.DoInMainThread(() =>
    {
        // To have the information is always helpful I'd say ;)
        Debug.LogWarning($"{e.GetType()} - {e.Message}/n{e.StackTrace}");
        UIManager.instance.logPanel.enabled = true;
        UIManager.instance.logPanel.text = "Servidor no disponible";
        UIManager.instance.HideUsernameSelection();
    }
}
```